# How do I run a Play Framework 2 app in dev mode on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, configuration, playframework, playframework-2.0

I created a staging app on heroku, and would like it to run in DEV mode.  Also, I have my procfile set to use application.production.conf, but I would like it to use application.staging.conf in my staging app.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an config variable to set this.  Like:

Procfile:

```
web: target/start -Dconfig.file=${CONFIG_FILE}
```

Then set the config for each environment:

```
heroku config:add --app my-staging CONFIG_FILE=application.staging.conf
heroku config:add --app my-prod CONFIG_FILE=application.production.conf
```

Comment: Whoops.  I think I got the ordering messed up.  Try: `heroku config:add CONFIG_FILE=application.staging.conf -a my-staging`  The `-a` just specifies the application that you are referring to.

Comment: -a still doesn't work, but `heroku config:add CONFIG_FILE=application.staging.conf --remote staging` seems to do the trick.  However, this still doesn't answer how to make the app start in DEV mode.  If I call `Play.isDev()`, it should return true.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to run in dev mode when using the `start` script.